# Percentage increase in price based on latest transaction date and previous transaction date

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

[image: Data Source Copy able format],

[image: Sample Data Image]

I want to get the percentage increase in price by **Country and City** based on latest transaction date and date of Previous Transaction.

How can I Query this? I am not getting it. This is What I have tried:

```
SELECT Country,City, Price
From tbl
Group by Country,City
```

Percentage increase = [( Latest Price - Previous Price ) / Previous Price] * 100

Expected Outout:
Unique Country and City Name + Percentage increase in Price.
Country | City | Percentage

Comment: Add some sample data and it will help to understand what you want

Comment: I have already added the sample data. please click the hyperlink.

Comment: What do you mean by 'price percentage'?   Average price?  if so avg(price) instead of price.

Comment: I mean percentage increase in price

Comment: Percentage increase = [( Latest Price - Previous Price ) / Previous Price] * 100

Comment: If you are using MS SQL 2012, take a look for LAG https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql

Comment: I am using sql server 2016

Comment: What do you expect the output to be based on your sample data?

Comment: Unique Country and City Name + Percentage increase in Price

Comment: LAG will solve your problem easily, remember that your first record don't have previous price and div by zero will cause the query failed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be overly complicated.

Set up some random data:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Cities') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE #Cities;
END;

CREATE TABLE #Cities
(
    Country VARCHAR(20)
   , City    VARCHAR(20)
);

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Data') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE #Data;
END;

CREATE TABLE #Data
(
    Country VARCHAR(20)
   , City    VARCHAR(20)
   , Price   DECIMAL(13, 4)
   , Date    DATETIME
);

INSERT INTO #Cities
VALUES      ('Country 1', 'City 1'), ('Country 1', 'City 2'), ('Country 1', 'City 3'), ('Country 2', 'City 4'), ('Country 2', 'City 5');


INSERT INTO #Data
SELECT Country
    , City
    , ROUND(RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) * 100, 4) AS Price
    , DATEADD(DAY, ROUND(RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) * 10, 0), GETDATE()) AS Date
FROM     #Cities
UNION
SELECT Country
    , City
    , ROUND(RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) * 100, 4)
    , DATEADD(DAY, ROUND(RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) * 10, 0), GETDATE())
FROM     #Cities;

--Delete duplicate dates

WITH data3 AS
(
SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Country,City,Date ORDER BY Country,City,Date) AS RN
FROM #Data
)
DELETE FROM data3 WHERE RN<>1
```

Query the data to get the most recent price, date and percentage increase:

```
SELECT        Dates.*
          , Latest.Price AS Latestprice
          , Previous.Price AS Previousprice
          , ((Latest.Price - Previous.Price) / Previous.Price) * 100 AS Percentageincrease
FROM
(
    SELECT    C.*
          , Latestdate.Latestdate
          , Previousdate.Previousdate
    FROM      #Cities AS C
            LEFT JOIN
    (
       --Latest Date for each county, city
       SELECT Country
           , City
           , MAX(Date) AS Latestdate
       FROM   #Data
       GROUP BY Country
            , City
    ) AS Latestdate ON Latestdate.Country = C.Country
                   AND Latestdate.City = C.City
            LEFT JOIN
    (
       --Previous Date for each county, city
       SELECT Country
           , City
           , Date AS Previousdate
       FROM
       (
          SELECT Country
              , City
              , Date
              , RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY Country
                                  , City ORDER BY Date DESC) AS Rank
          FROM   #Data
       ) AS A
       WHERE  Rank = 2
    ) AS Previousdate ON Previousdate.Country = C.Country
                    AND Previousdate.City = C.City
) AS Dates
JOIN #Data AS Latest ON Latest.Country = Dates.Country
                    AND Latest.City = Dates.City
                    AND Latest.Date = Dates.Latestdate
JOIN #Data AS Previous ON Previous.Country = Dates.Country
                     AND Previous.City = Dates.City
                     AND Previous.Date = Dates.Previousdate
```

And for comparison, using lag() to get the percentage increase for each date. Similar to Gordon's answer:

```
SELECT D.Country
    , D.City
    , D.Date
    , Lag(Date) OVER(PARTITION BY Country
                           , City ORDER BY Date) AS Previousdate
    , D.Price
    , Lag(Price) OVER(PARTITION BY Country
                            , City ORDER BY Date) AS Previousprice
    , 100 * (Price / Lag(Price) OVER(PARTITION BY Country
                                        , City ORDER BY Date) - 1) AS PercentageIncrease
FROM   #Data AS D;
```

Using lag to get the same results (latest info per city) as my first query:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT D.Country
        , D.City
        , D.Date
        , Lag(Date) OVER(PARTITION BY Country
                              , City ORDER BY Date) AS Previousdate
        , D.Price
        , Lag(Price) OVER(PARTITION BY Country
                               , City ORDER BY Date) AS Previousprice
        , 100 * (Price / Lag(Price) OVER(PARTITION BY Country
                                           , City ORDER BY Date) - 1) AS Percentageincrease
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Country
                                , City ORDER BY Date DESC) AS Rn
    FROM   #Data AS D
) AS A
WHERE  Rn = 1
ORDER BY Country
      , City;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `lag()`:

```
select t.*,
       100 * ((price / lag(price) over (partition by country, city order by t_date) - 1) as increase
from t;
```